# Parameter value '10212984.00' is out of range. in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a DB column with Decimal(9,2) data type and using EF to update the column. I am getting a parameter value out of range exception when I am trying to add 10212984. I am not sure why it's not letting it get added because it seems to be in range of the decimal storage value. Can someone please have a look and let me know what I am missing here.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not in the range of a `Decimal(9, 2)` The precision there is 9, meaning 9 decimal digits *in total*, and the scale of 2 means that 2 of the digits go after the decimal point, and 7 go before the decimal point.

So a field of type `Decimal(9, 2)` has valid values in the range -9,999,999.99 to 9,999,999.99. Your value is outside that range - it requires 8 digits before the decimal point.